# Broken and Mysterious Partitions

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-10

I have made a broken partition called safasf a long time ago when trying to fix my 400gb external hard drive (RIP broke from quick format lulz).

I need *`safasf`* deleted or something my knowledge isn't great on Partitions so I'm not sure if its needed or has some of my files.

From the screenshot below it also shows a weird volume Partition which probably stores windows or something but I've only noticed it recently but I'm pretty sure its been there since I had windows 8 but not certain.

[image]

Can anyone help me enlighten what these 2 are?

Comment: look into the disk management MMC snapin for details of the partitions: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disk-management-windows-7.htm

Comment: Not helpful of a comment, Disk Management now-a-days gives almost no help. But thank you for trying to help :)